# How To Validate Number in TextField in typescript (Ionic Framework)

Tags: html, angular, forms, ionic-framework

I want to validate only numbers are key-in in the input field for **IC NUMBER** text field. How should I parse the input entered by the user into int?

> ```
> <form>
>     <ion-list>
>
>       <ion-item>
>         <ion-input type="text"  placeholder="USERNAME" ></ion-input>
>       </ion-item>
>
>       <ion-item>
>         <ion-input type="password"  placeholder="PASSWORD"></ion-input>
>       </ion-item>
>
>       <ion-item>
>         <ion-input type="text"  placeholder="IC NUMBER"></ion-input>
>       </ion-item>
>
>              <div padding>
>            <button ion-button   color="dark" block>SUBMIT</button>
>         </div>
>      </ion-list>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: you might want to use https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/ for doing validation of input entered by user.

Comment: `input type="number"` should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel required pattern="\d">
```

use a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can take `type="tel"` which will allow user to enter only numbers.